# I have made a generic card to return card based on type prop, but I am getting an error [ts(2322)]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am new to React + Typescript. I was working on an E-commerce website, where I made some card components and a generic card component to return a particular card based on the `type` prop. Don't know why the error is coming.

**Error**- Type 'TodaysDealData | ReviewPurchaseData | CategoryDiscountData | KeepShoppingData[] | ProductDetailData' is not assignable to type 'TodaysDealData'.
Type 'ReviewPurchaseData' is missing the following properties from type 'TodaysDealData': id, name, image ts(2322)

**Here is my generic card component**

```
import React from 'react'
import { type GenericCard } from '../../../model'
import TodaysDealCard from '../Cards/TodaysDeal/TodaysDealCard'
import ProductDetailCard from '../Cards/ProductDetail/ProductDetailCard'
import ReviewPurchaseCard from '../Cards/ReviewPurchase/ReviewPurchaseCard'
import CategoryDiscountCard from '../Cards/CategoryDiscount/CategoryDiscountCard'
import KeepShoppingCard from '../Cards/KeepShopping/KeepShoppingCard'

const Card: React.FC<GenericCard> = ({ type, data }) => {
  const getCardType = (): JSX.Element => {
    switch (type) {
      case 'todays-deal':
        return <TodaysDealCard data={data} />
      case 'review-purchase':
        return <ReviewPurchaseCard data={data} />
      case 'category-discount':
        return <CategoryDiscountCard data={data} />
      case 'keep-shopping':
        return <KeepShoppingCard data={data} />
      case 'product-detail':
        return <ProductDetailCard data={data} />
      default:
        return <ProductDetailCard data={data} />
    }
  }

  const cardType = getCardType()

  return cardType
}

export default Card
```

**Here are the interfaces**

```
//Today's Deal card (1st Fold)
export interface TodaysDealData {
  id: string
  maxDiscount?: number
  fixedDiscount?: number
  timer?: number
  name: string
  image: string
}

//Review Purchase Card (2nd Fold)
export interface ReviewPurchaseData {
  img: string
}

interface Product {
  img: string
  name: string
}

//Category Discount Card (2nd Fold)
export interface CategoryDiscountData {
  id: string
  title: string
  products: Product[]
  cta: string
}

//Keep Shopping Card (2nd Fold)
export interface KeepShoppingData {
  id: string
  img: string
  name: string
  discount_price: number
  original_price: number
}

//Product Detail Card (3rd Fold)
export interface ProductDetailData {
  id: string
  img: string
  title: string
  rating: number
  discount?: number
  category?: string
  discount_price?: number
  original_price: number
  delivery_date: string
  free_delivery?: boolean
}

//Generic Card
export interface GenericCard {
  type:
    | 'todays-deal'
    | 'review-purchase'
    | 'category-discount'
    | 'keep-shopping'
    | 'product-detail'
  data:
    | TodaysDealData
    | ReviewPurchaseData
    | CategoryDiscountData
    | KeepShoppingData[]
    | ProductDetailData
}
```

**Here is a snapshot of Vscode**
[image: Generic Card component]

The error is not coming for any of the card components or where I am using these cards. The only place where the error is coming in the Generic card component. Although everything is working just fine but this error is bugging me.